# How to clear the all values from class list and int values in android?

Tags: android, class, variables

i have created one class in this i have used one arraylist hashmap and int counter variable 
if i want to clear all values from this class means class variable does not have any and values.here i show you how i was stored the value in list and counter variable.

i want clear all values from roundlooping class variables.

> Roundlooping.java

```
public class Roundlooping {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
    int counter;

}
```

> Mainactivity.java

```
Roundlooping rl = new Roundlooping();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> odata = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
ArrayList<Roundlooping> data = new ArrayList<Roundlooping>();

 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
 {
     do 
     {
         HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
         map.put(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_TIMERFROM, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_TIMERFROM)));
         map.put(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_TIMERTO, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_TIMERTO)));
         map.put(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_STUDIOFORMAT, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_STUDIOFORMAT)));
         odata.add(map);
         rl.list=odata;
        if(odata.size()>5)
        {
             rl.counter=odata.size();
             data.add(rl);
        }
        else
        {   
            rl.counter=0; 
            data.add(rl);
        }

   } while (cursor.moveToNext());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

first you want to make use of accessors and mutators

```
public class Roundlooping {

  private  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
  private  int counter;

  public void setList(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list){
    this.list = list;

  }

  public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getList(){
    return list;
  }

  public void setCounter(int counter){
    this.counter = counter;
  }

  public int getCounter(){
    return counter;
  }
}
```

and to clear the values just call the set method of `counter` and `list`

```
Roundlooping rl = new Roundlooping();
rl.setList(null); or rl.setList(new ArrayList<Hashmap<String,String>>());
rl.setCounter(0);
```

Comment: but this is clear all the values or particular position value i need to clear all the values